# calling F# functions from C# and getting null reference exceptions

Tags: c#, f#, closures, fastfunc

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 with the October 2009 F# CTP installed.

I'm trying to call some F# code from my C# program.  Most types of F# functions seem to work, but some are not getting initialized in F# and are throwing NullReferenceExceptions.  The ones doing this are closures and partially applied functions, i.e. things that appear in C# as FastFunc<> types.

Is there something I'm doing wrong or forgetting, or is this possibly a bug with F# or .NET?

*the code below is to demo the problem. I'm not actually trying to use this code in a real application.*
*also, within F#, everything works correctly. this is an F#-to-C# problem*

F#:

```
namespace FS      
module FunctionTypes =

    //these all work in c# as expected
    let Value = "value"

    let OneParam (str:string) = str

    let TwoParam (str:string) (str2:string) = str + " " + str2

    let Lambda =
        fun () -> "lambda"  


    //these functions are null references in C#
    // they do work as expected in F# interactive mode
    let PartialApplication = TwoParam "what's up"

    let Closure = 
        let o = new System.Object()
        fun (i:int) -> o.ToString() + i.ToString()

    let ClosureWrapper (i:int) =
        Closure i
```

C# (references F# project and FSharp.Core)

```
 //these work as expected:
        var oneParam = FS.FunctionTypes.OneParam("hey");
        var twoParam = FS.FunctionTypes.TwoParam("yeah", "you");
        var lambdaFunction = FS.FunctionTypes.Lambda();
        var value = FS.FunctionTypes.Value;
        //  in the May09 CTP, Value returned null, 
        //      so it must have been fixed in Oct09 CTP



 //these do not work--each throws a NullReferenceException.
        var partial = FS.FunctionTypes.PartialApplication.Invoke("hello");
        var closure = FS.FunctionTypes.Closure.Invoke(1);
        var closureWrapper = FS.FunctionTypes.ClosureWrapper(1);

 //  FS.FunctionTypes.Closure itself is null, 
 //  so is FS.FunctionTypes.PartialAppliction.
 //  FS.FunctionTypes.ClosureWrapper is a regular function, 
 //    but it calls Closure, which is null
```

Comment: Is the F# code compiled into an .exe or a .dll?

Comment: @Brian It's compiled to a .dll. The setup is two projects within the same solution, with the C# project referencing the F# project.

Comment: It should appear as FSharpFunc now and not FastFunc with the last CTP.

Comment: I cannot repro this.  I really think your C# is referencing a F# .exe and not a F# .dll.

Comment: @Brian  you're right. the output type on my F# project was console application, not a class library like I thought it was.  I guess that explains it. thanks

Comment: @Stringer Bell - oops, I didn't notice that name change!

Comment: FYI, when the next F# language spec update appears (spec to match Beta2/October CTP; maybe will appear in a week or so) it should spell out in excruciating detail the rules regarding when 'static initialization' happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me, i get "what's up hello", "System.Object1", "System.Object1" for partial, closure and closureWrapper vars. Are you referencing the good FSharp.Core assembly?

Comment: @Stringer Bell  yeah I was referencing FSharp.Core. The problem was my FSharp project was compiling to an exe... Everything is working for me now.